# Why $('#chat_input').val(chat[i]); print only first array element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Trying `alert()` method they print all masive elements

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("#monstriii").length){ //if class name is monstriii
        $("#chatBclan").click(); //chat button click
        setInterval(function(){ //interval to print next array element
            var chat = ["k", "story", "bro"]; // elements to prient
            for (var i=0; i<chat.length; i++){ // loop to go all array elements
                $('#chat_input').val(chat[i]); // input text to textbox
                $("#chat_btn_ok").click();  //button to send text to chatbox
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
});
```

Comment: It would help if you described what you're trying to do since your code is going to cause all sorts of problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to loop through the chat array every 3 seconds you have to put it outside your interval and increment inside. If you put a loop inside, the loop will be executed every interval and will display the chat array in an instant.

```js
var chat = ["k", "story", "bro"];
var i = 0;
setInterval(function(){ //interval to print next array element
     console.log(chat[i++]); // input text to textbox
      if (i >= chat.length) i = 0;
}, 3000);
```